# php8 supress Warning "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the below errors with php 8 that are occuring on one row only of a 150 row table.

I cannot see what is wrong here.

### Issue 1

```
SQL datetime value for column attUpdated 2021-10-06 00:00:00

45 public function getAttUpdatedDate() {
46         $date = $this->sqlData["attUpdated"];
47         return date("M j, Y", strtotime($date));


Deprecated
: strtotime(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string is deprecated in
C:\xampp3\htdocs\lessons\Ver_92_-_Photo-metadata-fixer-and-Sitemap-Maker\public_html\includes\classes\HelperAttraction.php
on line
47
```

### Issue 2

```
SQL int(11) value for column attClicksTotal 645

54 public function getAttClicksTotal() {
55         $views = $this->sqlData["attClicksTotal"];
56         $kViews = ($views <= 999) ? ($views) : (round($views/1000) . 'k');
57         return $kViews;

Warning
: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
C:\xampp3\htdocs\lessons\Ver_92_-_Photo-metadata-fixer-and-Sitemap-Maker\public_html\includes\classes\HelperAttraction.php
on line
55
```

Is there a way to block or supress specific php errors, not block all errors but just the two above that seem to be false errors from php. I do not want them showing in the browser?

Note that the code is working and rendering the results of the SQL in the browser correctly but still throwing these errors.

Answer (score 0):

"Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string is deprecated" , i had a similar issue, PHP 8 is strict with NULL values or division by 0 ...

-> return date("M j, Y", strtotime($date));

PHP expects a valid date format, if a NULL or 0 value is passed it may generate an error, you must check the $date variable before using it, ex. if it's null try passing '0000-00-00' or if you're in a loop use continue; to go directly to the next iteration

-> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

- Here too, you try to access to an array but is not an array, it is a NULL or false value who is returned, the same test it before treatment

Comment: Found issue. I still want to block the Warning "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool" because the information about file and line where code error is produced bears no relation to the source of the actual error in an object orientated project. This warning while indicative of an error is about as useful as a chocolate teapot for diagnostic purposes and I am therefore handling missing or null fields with a custom php script to overcome this.